# When I run this code I want to retrieve the GetDetails() method from the sub-class not the base class without changing the base class itself

Tags: c#, polymorphism

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CAudio Music = new CMusic(new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three" }, 120, "Hardcoded Title", "Advisory Music", new DateTime(2001, 05, 17), new TimeSpan(00, 05, 23), "Album", new string[] { "com1", "com2", "com3" }, "Genre");

            if (Music is CMusic)
            {
                Console.Write(Music.GetDetails());
            }
        }
    }

    abstract class CAudio
    {
        public CAudio(string[] artists, int bitrate, string title, string publisher, System.DateTime releaseDate, System.TimeSpan length)
        {
            this.Length = length;
            this.ReleaseDate = releaseDate;
            this.Publisher = publisher;
            this.Title = title;
            this.Bitrate = bitrate;
            this.Artists = artists;

        }

        private string sTitle;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return sTitle; }
            set { sTitle = value; }
        }

        private string sPublisher;
        public string Publisher
        {
            get { return sPublisher; }
            set { sPublisher = value; }
        }

        private DateTime dtReleaseDate;
        public DateTime ReleaseDate
        {
            get { return dtReleaseDate; }
            set { dtReleaseDate = value; }
        }

        private TimeSpan tsLength;
        public TimeSpan Length
        {
            get { return tsLength; }
            set { tsLength = value; }
        }

        private string[] sArtists;
        public string[] Artists
        {
            get { return sArtists; }
            set { sArtists = value; }
        }

        private int iBitrate;
        public int Bitrate
        {
            get { return iBitrate; }
            set { iBitrate = value; }
        }

        public string GetDetails()
        {
            string sDetails = "";
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "Title: ", Title, "\n");
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "Publisher: ", Publisher, "\n");
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "ReleaseDate: ", ReleaseDate.ToShortDateString(), "\n");
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "Length: ", Length, "\n");
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "Artists: ", string.Join(", ", Artists), "\n");
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "Bitrate: ", Bitrate, "\n");

            return sDetails;
        }

    }

    class CMusic : CAudio
    {
        private string sAlbum;
        public string Album
        {
            get { return sAlbum; }
            set { sAlbum = value; }
        }

        private string[] sComposers;
        public string[] Composers
        {
            get { return sComposers; }
            set { sComposers = value; }
        }

        private string sGenre;
        public string Genre
        {
            get { return sGenre; }
            set { sGenre = value; }
        }

        public new string GetDetails()
        {
            string sDetails = "";
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "Title: ", Title, "\n");
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "Publisher: ", Publisher, "\n");
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "ReleaseDate: ", ReleaseDate.ToShortDateString(), "\n");
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "Length: ", Length, "\n");
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "Artists: ", string.Join(", ", Artists), "\n");
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "Bitrate: ", Bitrate, "\n");
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "Album: ", Album, "\n");
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "Composers: ", string.Join(", ", Composers), "\n");
            sDetails = String.Concat(sDetails, "Genre: ", Genre, "\n");

            return sDetails;
        }

        public CMusic(string[] artists, int bitrate, string title, string publisher, System.DateTime releaseDate, System.TimeSpan length, string album, string[] composers, string genre)
            : base(artists, bitrate, title, publisher, releaseDate, length)
        {
            Album = album;
            Composers = composers;
            Genre = genre;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question

Comment: @lc. It's in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast it to CMusic:

```
if (Music is CMusic)
{
    Console.Write(((CMusic)Music).GetDetails());
}
```

However, in this case it seems more appropriate to actually declare the method as virtual in the base class and then override it in the sub-class.

Comment: thak you very much... and i just got another way of casting

Answer (score 1):

in your base class:

```
public virtual string GetDetails() { /* ... */ }
```

in your sub-class:

```
public override string GetDetails() { /* ... */ }
```

From your comments it appears you do not want to change the base-class because of "coding for the base class".  There is nothing wrong in abstract classes providing boiler-plate functionality, in-fact it's a common idiom.

For "true", no implementation bases, you could consider using an interface (an interface isn't an abstract class, really.. it's a contract that any class that implements the interface must adhere to):

```
public interface IAudio
{
    public string GetDetails();
}

public class CAudio : IAudio
{
    public string GetDetails() { /* ... */ }
}
```

In fact, it's perfectly acceptable to use both an interface *and* an abstract class to provide boiler plate functionality:

```
public interface IAudio { /* .. as above .. */ }

public abstract class CAUdio : IAudio
{
     // provide boiler-plate functionality
     public virtual string GetDetails() { /* ... */ }
}

public class CMusic : CAudio
{
     public override string GetDetails() { /* .. specialise */ }
}
```

Comment: This could use a bit more detail.  The OP did say that he didn't want to change the base class.

Comment: if i use override i will have to use abstract in the method and by so doing i will not be "coding for a base-class" if u know th term

Comment: @ThembaMabaso, you don't have to make the method abstract at all.:)  There's nothing wrong in coding for a base-class.

Comment: @ThembaMabaso As Moo-Juice said, use `virtual`, which allows a base class implementation. If you really can't, or don't want to, change the base class, you'll have to use a `new` method, but that will break inheritance and such.

Comment: Thanks to the interface idea we actually learnt that they can be used as an option as well. :) (y)